# curl bot not working write

Tags: php, curl

I want to write a script that would be parse the time table of my university and save it to disc. I use curl, to do it. The main link to time table [here](http://cist.kture.kharkov.ua/ias/app/tt/f?p=778:201:641001457784406%3a%3a:201%3aP201_FIRST_DATE,P201_LAST_DATE,P201_GROUP,P201_POTOK:01.02.2012,30.07.2012,2423461,0%3a), if open it in browser I can see the content, but if I try to open it in curl i have failure =(

Here is source code of php script:

```
<?


    $url = "http://cist.kture.kharkov.ua/ias/app/tt/f?p=778:201:128623920522090:::201:P201_FIRST_DATE,P201_LAST_DATE,P201_GROUP,P201_POTOK:01.02.2012,30.07.2012,2423461,0:";

    $ch = curl_init();


    $cookieFile = tempnam ( dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies/", 'cookie-' );



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );

    $ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.26 Safari/535.11";


    //$headers = array('HOST: cist.kture.kharkov.ua','CONNECTION: keep-alive','CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0','USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.26 Safari/535.11','ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','REFERER: http://google.com.ua',  'ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch','ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4','ACCEPT_CHARSET: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    $counter = 0;
    while($info['redirect_url']!= "")
    {
        echo "url => ". $url."<br />\n";
        echo "redirect => ". $info['redirect_url']."<br /><br />\n";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $info['redirect_url']);
        $url = $info['redirect_url'];
        $data = curl_exec($ch);


        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        $counter++;

        if($counter>100)
            break;
    }



        foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
            echo $key . " -> ".$value."<br />\n";
        }           
    $html = htmlspecialchars($data);
    echo "<pre>$html</pre>";

    echo $cont;?>
```

In result I have an empty page :( Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided has a 302 redirect, so you won't get the schedule, you would have to follow the redirect in order to get it.

More specifically, look at the "Location" header, and use that location.

Comment: there is cycle in my script what follow on redirect url, it is follow two times and stop, but $data is empty =(

Comment: You're right, it keeps redirecting. Maybe it has something to do with the cookie the server sends. Try to send that cookie as well in subsequent requests and see if that makes any difference.